# How to register custom post types in a plugin?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-development, hooks, actions

I'm using toscho's [Plugin Class Demo](https://gist.github.com/toscho/3804204) code as a foundation for a plugin I'm developing. Amongst other things, my plugin registers a custom post type.

```
public function plugin_setup() {
    $this->plugin_url = plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ );
    $this->plugin_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
    $this->load_language( 'myplugindomain' );
    // more stuff: register actions and filters
    add_action( 'init', array( 'MyPluginClass', 'register_my_post_types' ) );
}

public function register_my_post_types() {
    $labels = array( ..... );

    $args = array(
        'show_ui' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'), 
        'has_archive' => true
    );

    register_post_type('mycustomtype', $args);
}
```

My question is, is it good practice to hook my `register_my_post_types()` function to the `init` hook? Or would it be better to call it directly in the `plugin_setup()` function?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `init` hook is the first hook allowed. If called earlier it won't work.

See WP Codex: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/

> Create or modify a post type. register_post_type should only be invoked through the 'init' action. It will not work if called before 'init', and aspects of the newly created or modified post type will work incorrectly if called later.

Answer (score 2):

I always do it in the init hook.  If you do it in setup it every time they change setup or settings you will be registering that post type.  Plus if your settings change the url or any portion of the new cpt you'll want those active before you change them.